# PHP custom postcard

Tags: php, image, gd

i am creating a new feature on my site that allow people to send postcard to friends. in this section they can choose the image they want to send (they already uplaoded the image to their profile -> my pictures section)

i am using the php function to create the text that goes on the right but how can i add another image to this image with the text?

i use `imagettftext` to create the text, `imagecreatefromjpeg` to open the main image (see below) and `imagedestroy` when im done

thanks

i am using this postcard:
[image: postcard-template.jpg]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First you will have to crop the image to fit in your postcard. 
Based on your image here's what you have to do:

```
<?php

$sourceImage = './postcard-template.jpg';
$uploadedImage = '/path/to/image/hong-kong2.jpg'; // let's get hong kong as example
$mime = '';
$font = '/path/to/font/arial.ttf'; 

function CroppedThumbnail($source, $width, $height, &$mime) {
  $data = getimagesize($source);
  $sourceWidth = $data[0];
  $sourceHeight = $data[1];
  $mime = $data['mime'];
  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
  $sourceRatio = $sourceWidth/$sourceHeight;
  if (($width/$height) > $sourceRatio) {
    $newHeight = $width/$sourceRatio;
    $newWidth = $width;
  }
  else {
    $newWidth = $height*$sourceRatio;
    $newHeight = $height;
  }
  $croppedImage = imagecreatetruecolor(round($newWidth), round($newHeight));
  imagecopyresampled($croppedImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);
  $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  imagecopyresampled($thumb, $croppedImage, 0, 0, (($newWidth/2)-($width/2)), (($newHeight/2)-($height/2)), $width, $height, $width, $height);
  imagedestroy($croppedImage);
  imagedestroy($image);
  return $thumb;
}

// Create the cropped image first
$newThumb = CroppedThumbnail($uploadedImage,240,315, $mime);
switch($mime) {
  case 'image/gif':
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($sourceImage);  
    break;
  case 'image/jpeg':
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImage);  
    break;
  case 'image/png':
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($sourceImage);  
    break;
  default:
    // error or stop script
    break;
}
$message = "this is some text\nsome other text\ntext text";

imagettftext($image, 21, 0, 320, 255, imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0), $font, $message);
imagecopy($image, $newThumb, 40, 40, 0, 0, 240, 315); 
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image); 
imagedestroy($image);
```

For example I use this image ( needs to be cropped ) :

[image: testimage]

then it will output:

[image: final]

Answer (score 0):

Use [imagecopymerge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) to copy the photo onto the post card

```
bool imagecopymerge ( resource $dst_im , resource $src_im , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $src_w , int $src_h , int $pct )
```